# Keycloak LetsEncrypt Nginx Reverse Proxy Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak, lets-encrypt, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to setup an keycloak instance with an ssl connection over an nginx proxy my 'docker ps' output:

```
d7fd473cc77b        jboss/keycloak                           "/opt/jboss/tools/do…"   34 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8443/tcp                                auth
76e757bbe129        mariadb                                  "sh -c ' echo 'CREAT…"   34 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                          backend-database
d99e23470955        stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened-latest      "/bin/sh -c '/run.sh…"   34 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:21->21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30000->30000/tcp, 30001-30009/tcp   ftp-server
95f4fbdea0de        wordpress:latest                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       80/tcp                                                          wordpress
b3e40ca6de48        mariadb:latest                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       3306/tcp                                                        database
e5c12bb5ba52        nginx                                    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp                        nginx-web
c0ac90a6c408        jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion   "/bin/bash /app/entr…"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes                                                                       nginx-letsencrypt
33ae7de5f598        jwilder/docker-gen                       "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes                                                                       nginx-gen
```

As you can see at the above console output, I am also running an instance of wordpress in a docker container and this works like a charm, no problems with unsigned or invalid ssl certificates, just erverything fine. But when I am trying to call the web interface of keycloak over the domain with the corresponding port (in my case: 8080), I got the following error:

```
Fehlercode: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

And when I am trying to call the web interface over the ip address also with the corresponding port,  I got the message that the connection isn't safe.

Hopefully this are enough information for you guys, to figure out what I've done wrong.

So far,
Daniel

Comment: Hello Daniel, welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry but the information is not enough, the docker compose file is missing.

Comment: can you show you nginx (keycloak related) config? it seems like keycloak isn't aware of an ssl connection, which makes sense when you just access it through nginx, but then you shouldn't call keycloak directly on port 8080